# How to save an image with text overlay without using canvas?

Tags: javascript

In vanilla JS I create a div with an image and 2 p tags and that I append to the DOM. I position the p tags over the image using CSS. Is it possible to make the resulting image with text over it be able to be saved/downloaded without using canvas?

Comment: i don't think it is possible without the `Canvas API` (it may be but it seems too complex i might say). I think, if possible, use a backend language where you can perform some image processing and have the desired outcome either saved to the server or sent back to the browser (both cases allow you to download the resulting image).

Comment: @ths I appreciate the confirmation. I was thinking the exact same thing, I just wanted to double check. Thank you. I hope you have a good day.